# How to bind table with uploaded csv file in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, csv

How do you Bind table in `angularJS` with uploaded CSV file.

```
app.controller("TestController", function ($scope) {

    $scope.Name = "Ankur vijay";
    $scope.processData = function (allText) {
        // split content based on new line
        var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        var headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');
        var lines = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
            // split content based on comma
            var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
            if (data.length == headers.length) {
                var tarr = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                    tarr.push(data[j]);
                }
                lines.push(tarr);
            }
        }
        $scope.data = lines;
    };
```

Comment: show what have you try?

Comment: Nothing.. started yeasterdat but even now have no idea from where to start